# How to create 'Tree view inside a drop down box ' using angular directive

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I created tree view structure and custom drop down using angular directive but i actually need   a drop-down box with tree structured view using angular directive.

Am very new to this angular framework so please help-me to solve this problem.

Comment: I got some references from these examples in JSFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/8ApLX/5/

http://jsfiddle.net/eu81273/8LWUc/18/

Answer (score 3):

I have created one Multi select hierarchical drop down using ivhTreeView. May be you can include it into directive and use it.

[Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/wOo98cSXa12rRLZO85lr)

```
<div class="dropdown-with-ivhTreeView">
  <div class="dropDown" ng-click="onClickShowIVHDropdown($event)">
    <div class="dropDownButton">
      <div class="dropDownButtonIcon"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropDownContent">
    <!-- INSERTING ivhTreeView : START -->
    <input type="text" ng-model="myQuery" class="searchBox">
    <div class="ivhTree" ivh-treeview="stuff"
      ivh-treeview-expand-to-depth="10"
      ivh-treeview-filter="myQuery"
      ivh-treeview-use-checkboxes="true">
    </div>
    <!-- INSERTING ivhTreeView : END -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this link to create tree structure inside select dropdown box.
It uses group by inside `ng-options`
[click here](http://plnkr.co/edit/LqeGqg1HdOIkiMQrKn72?p=preview)